# Partial wake lock power drain in Android phones

Tags: android

I am creating a remote service that keeps the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK in order to continually
do some background work. What range of power drain should I expect in the Android devices
from this? On my devices, it eats anything between 30 min and 2 hours of battery life as measured from full charge.

Comment: There are way too many variables: CPU speed/power usage, battery capacity, what the background work is doing, what other things might get control and do work because the device happens to be powered on (e.g., non-`_WAKEUP` alarm with `AlarmManager`), etc. Suffice it to say that if you truly mean "continually", what you describe sounds like an open invitation for one-star ratings on Google Play...

Comment: I see. It would be great if some data was available just for a simple lock with an app that does near zero work, for example, on fresh installed phones (the Google guys might have this). This would allow us, developers, to gauge if our apps are feasible before launching them to the market.